# Convergence in probability of parameters of normal distribution implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

Suppose $(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} (\mu, \sigma^2)$. Does this imply that we have $\mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

I.e., Does convergence in probability of the parameters of the normal distribution imply convergence to a normal distribution? If not, are there some additional conditions that need to be imposed?

Comment: What is the convergence you intend in $\mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$? Note that these are stochastic processes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use characteristic functions and note that weak convergence is preserved by continuous functions.

Comment: My understanding was this only held when $(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \rightarrow (\mu, \sigma^2)$ as opposed to in probability $(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2) \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} (\mu, \sigma^2)$

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem holds under convergence in probability also.

Comment: Take conditional ch fn given mean and variance then take expectation. Apply DCT at the end.